# VB.NET-FolderBrowserDialog: browse folders in android device

Tags: android, vb.net

With my small app for Windows I want to browse a folder in an Android device when it is connected to the usb port and then import all files from the chosen folder to a pc folder. I tried to use FolderBrowserDialog but it doesn't work. The device is shown but if I select any folder in the device the OK button becomes disabled. For c:, d: e: and so on it works. Any suggestion please? 
Really thank you

Comment: Can you add in some piece of code? Can't even know what is "OK" button

Comment: Well, so far I have only FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()  used when I push a button. The browser Dialog opens showing all disks and the Android device. If I select a folder in, let's say, c:\  "OK" button works. If I select any folder in the android device the "OK" button becomes colored gray and and disabled.

Comment: It's make confused at 1st time. Got your idea. The reason is simple, Your phone's storage is generic hierarchical file system. It's totally different with FAT32 or NTFS :)

Comment: Thank you, got it. Do you know if there is other ways for that?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comment the FolderBrowserDialog can't access Portable Device, therefore, you can tried with some practice below (3rd party library):

http://dev.flauschig.ch/wordpress/?p=212 --> He used FolderBrowserDialog same like you, but reliased it's no use

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1512685 --> This required 3.5 .NET