# Transfer files between computer and phone

Tags: vb.net, filesystems, android-sdcard

I want to make a VB program that automatically copies files from my computer to my phone's SD card.

The problem is that I can't get the true directory paths on my phone's SD card, only "phone/sd card/" which I obviously can't use as a path in VB.

Is there a way I can find out the real path or is there any other way to copy files?

Comment: You might be able to use [AndroidLib - .NET Android Device Communication and Management Library](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1512685). I found the link in [VB.NET-FolderBrowserDialog: browse folders in android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318608/vb-net-folderbrowserdialog-browse-folders-in-android-device).

Comment: all the classes that i need are in c# unfortunately. i dont't know how i can use them anyway in my vb project